# Creating new columns with a list of JSON column

Tags: python, json, list

I have the following data with a column which is essentially a list of json:

```
[{
"$id": "2",
"Name": "IDMAWH-L853902$",
"Mail": "ENTA.AD.COM",
"Type": "account"
}, {
"$id": "3",
"Address": "::ffff:10.192.20.125",
"Type": "ad"
}]
[{
    "$id": "2",
    "MailboxPrimaryAddress": "bw165@gmail.com",
    "Upn": "bw165@gmail.com",
    "AadId": "936b3d90-b86c-4dba-812d-8f6025c1e379",
    "RiskLevel": "None",
    "Type": "mailbox",
    "Urn": "urn:UserEntity:1ccd1b06205baec05fe19e55e0d602c6",
    "Source": "OATP",
    "FirstSeen": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}, {
    "$id": "3",
    "Recipient": "bw165@gmail.com",
    "Urls": ["https://towardsdatascience.com/cleaning-and-extracting-json-from-pandas-dataframes-f0c15f93cb38"]}
```

I want to get the "account","Urls" & "IP" as individual columns. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You have two lists that aren't in a container. And there's no closing `]` for the second list.

Comment: Why is there no `Type` field in the last object?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the list of dictionaries. If it contains one of the columns you want, copy that value the corresponding column of the result.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)

for item in data:
    id = item['$id']
    for col in ('account', 'Urls', 'IP'):
        if col in item:
            $result[id][col] = item[col]

result = list(result.values())
```